# Does the RSF control 70% of Sudan's territory and 2/3 of its inhabitants?

Tags: war, sudan

There's embedded video at the end of [this 24 Jan 2024 al-Jazeera article](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/1/24/uae-denies-sending-weapons-to-sudans-rsf-paramilitary-report) in a certain Waleed Mabido claims that [Hemedti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemedti), the leader of the 'rebel' [RSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_Support_Forces), controls 70% of the territory of Sudan and "30 million" inhabitants (out of a population of 46 million or so)--thus 2/3 of the population, approximately.

Are these claims approximately true (as well as that can be known during a civil war)?

There are [other sources](https://adf-magazine.com/2023/11/rsf-advances-give-it-control-over-half-of-sudan/) (US based, it seems-- "Africa Defense Forum (ADF) magazine is published quarterly by U.S. Africa Command") that claimed somewhat earlier (28 November 2023) that the RSF controlled 'over half' of Sudan.

Wikipedia however appears to provide the exactly opposite [picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:War_in_Sudan_(2023).svg), at least in terms of territory:

[image]

But I'm not sure what the sources for that map are. One might suspect that's due to changes on the ground in the meantime, but Wikipedia hardly reports any of those, at least on the history of that map.

[image]

Comment: Madibo has been moderately cited by a number of other Al-J articles on Sudan (so they seem use him as an expert on the topic), although al-J didn't seem to cite him for *that* fact/claim about control in print.